# Extract second element from every item in a list

Tags: r

This additonal information might help. Here is what I am trying to do:
This throws more light but here is what I am trying to. Lets say you have a data like the one below –

```
Region      Open    Store
120..141       +    France
145..2115      +    Germany
3322..5643     +    Wales
5646..7451     -    Scotland
7454..8641     -    Mexico
8655..9860     -    India
9980..11413    +    Zambia
11478..1261    -    Nicaragua
12978..1318    +    Sweeden
```

What I was trying to do was to pick find the difference between the second element (141) and the consecutive first element (143) and if they meet a certain value and they have the same sign ( + or -), list all their stores together.

Comment: If you have another question (which you clearly do) then ask another question.  DO NOT completely edit away the original question to replace it with your new question.

Comment: thanks. That was unintentional on my part. any insight will be helpful

Comment: Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 10):

Use `sapply` and pass to it `[` as the function and tell it you want to extract the second element.

```
# Create your data set
dat <- list(c(100, 150), c(201, 202), c(147, 269), c(301, 401))
dat
#[[1]]
#[1] 100 150
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 201 202
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 147 269
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 301 401
#
sapply(dat, "[", 2)
#[1] 150 202 269 401
```

Comment: Your insight really helped but how do i apply the second part of my question (Also, I will like to find a way to calculate the difference between the preceding second element and the successive first element ( example difference between 150 ( second element of [[1]] and 201 first element of list [[2]]. Any help will be appreciated) ?

Comment: Well you now know how you can extract elements easily.  Why don't you take some time to think about how you could use that to solve your "second" question.

Comment: Sure. That makes sense. Raising the gear of my thinking cap

Comment: If I could get a little guide for my other question, it will be helpful. I seem not to find the right material for it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [@Dason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003565/dason) that understanding the mechanics are important (i.e. you can't treat R like PHP), but if 2.6 hours of fiddling still has you stumped, this might help:

```
dat <- list(c(100, 150), c(201, 202), c(147, 269), c(301, 401))
second <- sapply(dat, "[", 2) 
first <- sapply(dat[2:length(second)], "[", 1)
second[1:length(first)] - first
```

Knowing more of what you're really trying to do would help since I'm not fully convinced that's the final result you're looking for.

Comment: This throws more light but here is what I am trying to. Lets say you have a data like the one below –
Region Open Store
120..141 + France
145..2115 + Germany
2145..3254 + Italy
3322..5643 + Wales
5646..7451 - Scotland
7454..8641 - Mexico
8655..9860 - India
9980..11413 + Zambia
11478..12614 - Nicaragua
12978..13187 + Sweeden


What I was trying to do was to pick find the difference between the second element (141) and the consecutive first element (143) and if they meet a certain value and they have the same sign ( + or -), list all their stores together.

Comment: `dput()` is your friend! if you can run that on your data source and provide it here, I'm sure it could help get you to an answer (even if you have to munge some of the data to make it publicly post-able).

Comment: Not sure if the dput() applies to my question ( please check above)

Comment: Actually having even a portion of the real data object (vs descriptions of the data object) you're trying to work with might help folks fully understand what you're trying to do and produce working code.

Comment: That why I gave the example(Region, Open, Store) above. Its just that I am dealing with thousands of rows of data. What I did first was to read the data, then applied the strsplit function to deal with 124..125 issue. I also used the sapply function function to identify the first and second element of the region row. The example  I gave above is the snippet of the raw file. any insight will help

Comment: @user3424320 You obviously didn't look into what dput actually does.  It makes it so that we can copy the code produced by dput to obtain the data/object of interest.  You posted what your data looks like - this isn't enough to make it easily reproducible.  It's the difference between saying "My data is 3, 9, 2, 3" and saying "You can get my data by c(3, 9, 2, 3)".  The second one can be directly put into R.  There are other things we get when you use dput - mainly it retains the types so we know if the data is numeric or character or factor in R.  Using dput isn't an unreasonable request.