# split list and keep first value in R

Tags: r

On the following list, I would like to keep first value of each item.

```
[[1]]
[1] "Avatar" "\xe6"  
[[2]]
[1] "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End" "\xe6"                                    
[[3]]
[1] "Spectre" "\xe6"
```

To look like

```
[[1]]
[1] "Avatar" 
[[2]]
[1] "Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End"                                 
[[3]]
[1] "Spectre"
```

Comment: Here's another related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22430365/5325862

Answer (score 1):

An option is `lapply`

```
lapply(lst1, `[`, 1)
```

Or using `first` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(lst1, first)
```